# Why is that I still cannot import the provider/provider.dart package in my flutter project after having installed the provider package successfully?

Tags: flutter-provider

**pubspec.yaml**
dependencies:

flutter:
sdk: flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRKGE.png)
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
provider: ^5.0.0

[This is the error that I found while importing the provider package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRKGE.png)

Comment: reload vscode. Can also do ctrl-p and type ">reload" and a suggestion will pop up for it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I'm still stuck in this issue; reload doesn't work. I've tried the same process of installing and importing the provider but same error occurs.